# PyQT Layout Box

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a problem here that is quite obvious but I can't find a solution. I am new to PyQt and PyQtGraph.

Here are the relevant codes:

```
 verticalGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Waveforms")
 layoutV = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

 waveformPlot1 = pg.PlotWidget()
 waveformPlot2 = pg.PlotWidget()
 waveformPlot3 = pg.PlotWidget()

 waveformPlot1.plotItem.plot(self.time, self.data_plot[0])
 layoutV.addWidget(waveformPlot1)

 waveformPlot2.setYRange(-30000, 30000, padding=0.01)
 waveformPlot2.setXRange(0, self.timeDuration, padding=0.01)
 layoutV.addWidget(waveformPlot2)

 waveformPlot3.setYRange(-30000, 30000, padding=0.01)
 layoutV.addWidget(waveformPlot3)
```

Here are the images to my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6MR.jpg | 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L88PE.jpg

As you can see in the first image, I only placed a plot with data on waveformPlot1 and made waveformPlot2 and waveformPlot3 an empty plot widgets for testing. So now, my problem is, when I decided to attach another data that is expected to be plotted in waveformPlot2 widget (in order from plot1-plot3), hence, it is 
plotted in waveformPlot3 widget. (see second image)

```
 waveformPlot2.plotItem.plot(self.time, self.data_plot[0])
```

I notice that it is because of the layout that it follows where it ends, so my 2nd plot data was plotted on the 3rd widget

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry and thank you for your reminder.. Edited it. I hope someone will still notice my question. :)

Comment: @Patrick please read up on the link to "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". Basically: the code you post should be runnable by anyone who has the right Python and pyQt version installed (and please state which versions you use).

Comment: have you confirmed that the plot widgets are being placed in the QVBoxLayout in the order that you would expect?